# Why after pull from origin/master, the local/master wants to push again?

Tags: git, github, sourcetree

I am new to git and I am using sourcetree in my current project. Everytime I do a pull request from my origin feature branch to origin/master the local master inside sourcetree wants to pull. So far so good, since the local master wants the new changes, however right after I do a pull to local master, it shows me to push from local master to origin/master. Origin master was up to date and still is.

Why is that happening? Any ideas whats a pull with commit merges doing to local master? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a habit, you should `pull` or `rebase` (which is better is a subject of great debate and is up to your source control admin) before any `commit` and `push` to `origin`, ensuring your copy of the repo has the latest versions AND that you can resolve conflicts before you `push`.   If you `pull` and resolve conflicts (if there are any), your repository will have changed (whether there are conflicts you resolved or not), which means that `origin` is now one `commit` behind.  That's why you keep getting prompted.